# How to access wmi in python?

Tags: python, windows, wmi, openhardwaremonitor

So I am trying to access the data from [here](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/OpenHardwareMonitor-WMI.pdf)

in Python. As you can see, it uses wmi. I have tried to use wmi in python before but I am having trouble interpreting the data they are giving me. Please be patient with me as I am a noob to how wmi works. It says that the wmi data is stored in root/OpenHardwareMontor and that it uses two different wmi classes(Hardware and Sensor). But all this information is going over my head.

could someone please give me some sample code to read some data from this?

For example, the code to check cpu core 1 frequency.

EDIT: i have sort of got it working. i run this code:

```
for Temperature in c.sensor():
    print Temperature.identifier
    print Temperature.value
```

and i get this:

```
/hdd/0/load/0
37.6608924866
/intelcpu/0/temperature/1
53.0
/intelcpu/0/temperature/0
42.0
/ram/data/1
2.88324356079
/intelcpu/0/load/2
1.53846144676
/hdd/0/temperature/0
43.0
/intelcpu/0/load/0
2.30768918991
/intelcpu/0/clock/1
1463.29663086
/intelcpu/0/clock/0
133.02696228
/intelcpu/0/clock/2
1463.29663086
/ram/load/0
49.224521637
/ram/data/0
2.79517364502
/intelcpu/0/load/1
3.07692289352
```

how can i request **only** the value associated with the identifier /intelcpu/0/temperature/1 ignoring all other values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most simple example to use WMI:

```
c = wmi.WMI()
wql = "Select * From Win32_SerialPort"
for item in c.query(wql):
    print item
```

Output Example:

```
instance of Win32_SerialPort
{
    Availability = 2;
    Binary = TRUE;
    Caption = "SpectrumAnalyzer1 (COM15)";
    ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
    ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_SerialPort";
    Description = "SpectrumAnalyzer1";
    DeviceID = "COM15";
    MaxBaudRate = 128000;
    MaximumInputBufferSize = 0;
    MaximumOutputBufferSize = 0;
    Name = "SpectrumAnalyzer1 (COM15)";
    OSAutoDiscovered = TRUE;
    PNPDeviceID = "USB\\VID_10C4&PID_ED00\\1269376";
    PowerManagementCapabilities = {1};
    PowerManagementSupported = FALSE;
    ProviderType = "RS232 Serial Port";
    SettableBaudRate = TRUE;
    SettableDataBits = TRUE;
    SettableFlowControl = TRUE;
    SettableParity = TRUE;
    SettableParityCheck = TRUE;
    SettableRLSD = TRUE;
    SettableStopBits = TRUE;
    Status = "OK";
    StatusInfo = 3;
    Supports16BitMode = FALSE;
    SupportsDTRDSR = TRUE;
    SupportsElapsedTimeouts = TRUE;
    SupportsIntTimeouts = TRUE;
    SupportsParityCheck = TRUE;
    SupportsRLSD = TRUE;
    SupportsRTSCTS = TRUE;
    SupportsSpecialCharacters = TRUE;
    SupportsXOnXOff = TRUE;
    SupportsXOnXOffSet = TRUE;
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = ".......";
};
```

You can access each `item` by:

```
myQuery = c.query(wql)
myQuery.Availability
```

Output:

```
2
```

For more information, try the WMI [cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html).

Edit #1:

Using if statements and `in` you can do what you want.

```
for Temperature in c.sensor():
    if "/intelcpu/0/temperature/1" in Temperature.identifier:
        print Temperature.identifier
        print Temperature.value
```

Comment: ok i semi-figured-it-out using the "cockbook". i ran this code: for Temperature in c.sensor():
 print Temperature.name
 print Temperature.value and it worked, but it printed out every single temperature sensor name/value. how can i grab a single value only?

Comment: @user1803425 Can you add the output to your post?

Comment: when i ran for Temperature in c.sensor():
 print Temperature.name
 print Temperature.value it returned Used Space
37.6607666016
CPU Core #2
56.0
CPU Core #1
46.0
Available Memory
2.88618087769
CPU Core #2
2.30768918991
Temperature
42.0
CPU Total
2.30768918991
CPU Core #1
1463.296875
Bus Speed
133.026992798
CPU Core #2
1463.296875
Memory
49.1727905273
Used Memory
2.79223632812
CPU Core #1
2.30768918991

Comment: It's hard to understand, can you clearfy better? add the data to your post (using edit) not as a comment.

Comment: ok. i have added the information to my post. does that help clarify what i am saying?

Comment: @user1803425 you can see my edit.... you need to read more about `strings` and `in` at python...